# Reference Entity Framework 6 in .NET Core through another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I added a new ASP.NET Core Web Application (Web API) project in my solution.

I understand the fact that I can't use EF6 in this project but I would like to know if there is a way to make another project (using .NET Framework) do the work and pass the data back to the .NET Core project.

Here is my code :

. Controller (.NET Core)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public UserDto Get(Int32 id)
    {
        Models.UserDto user = UserHelper.Get(id);

        if (user == null)
            throw new Exception();

        return user;
    }
}
```

. Helper (.Net Core)

```
public class UserHelper
{
    public static UserDto Get(int id)
    {
        User user = UserController.Get(id);
        return Map(user);
    }

    private static UserDto Map(User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            return null;

        UserDto dto = new UserDto();
        dto.Id = user.ID;
        dto.Lastname = user.LastName;
        dto.Firstname = user.FirstName;
        dto.Email = user.Email;
        dto.Username = user.Username;
        dto.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
        dto.CustomerId = user.CustomerID;
        return dto;
    }
}
```

. Controller (.NET Framework)

```
public static User Get(int id, UserStateCriteria criteria)
    {
        InputCheckerHelper.CheckNull<UserStateCriteria>(criteria, "criteria");

        using (NContext uow = new NContext())
        {
            var query = uow.Users
                           .Include(u => u.ConsoleUsers)
                           .Include(u => u.Devices)
                           .Include(u => u.Culture)
                           .Include(u => u.Product)
                           .Include(u => u.Customer)
                           .Include(u => u.ProductCredentials.Select(pc => pc.Database.DatabaseConnector))
                           .Include(u => u.ProductCredentials.Select(pc => pc.Database.DatabaseConnector.Methods.Select(m => m.Headers)))
                           .Include(u => u.ProductCredentials.Select(pc => pc.Database.DatabaseConnector.Methods.Select(m => m.Parsers)))
                           .Include(u => u.ProductCredentials.Select(pc => pc.Database.DatabaseConnector.Methods.Select(m => m.ConfigurableConnectorFieldRenamings)))
                           .Include(u => u.ProductCredentials.Select(pc => pc.Database.DatabaseConnector.Methods.Select(m => m.ConfigurableConnectorErrorMappings)))
                           .Include(u => u.Subscription.Edition)
                           .Where(u => u.ID == id);

            query = ApplyStateCriteriaOnQuery(criteria, query);

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

I have search SO and other web sites in vain for a case similar to mine but it was not very helpful.

I am only asking here because on microsoft's site  [it says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6) :

> The recommended way to use Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET Core application is to put the EF6 context and model classes in a class library project that targets the full framework.

But after referencing my BLL and DAL project I get :

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Comment: Do you have referenced the full .Net framework in your MVC app and class libraries? Do you have checked your nuget packages and versions etc.?

Comment: EntityFramework v6.1.3 is installed on both referenced project and they are present in my .csproj as `<ProjectReference Include="..\Nomalys.Server.BLL\N.Server.BLL.csproj" />`

Comment: Without project files it's difficult to guess what's going wrong. Have you checked the example solution by microsoft? https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/data/entity-framework-6/sample

Comment: Have you tried adding EntityFramework to your MVC project?

Comment: @Scrobi I tried but got `Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'N.Server.Core.WebAPI'.` @Spindler I am still exploring their solution.

Comment: Most important are probably: 1) target platform has to be full .net framework. see csproj file for this - `<TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>`. 2) referencing EF6 in all projects (as @Scrobi said)

Answer (score 1):

You can if an only if your Core app is actually running on the full framework, as well. The reason is simple, you can't reference a full framework library from a non-full framework project. The API footprint is not the same.

However, even if you're running on the full framework, you still must have a separate project (a class library, for example) to actually house your context and migrations. This is because the PMC commands you need to use with EF6 aren't compatible with a Core project.